# Does integrability on a completion of a measure imply the integrability on the measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I was studying the dominated convergence theorem and the question came up.

My question is as follows.

If $f \in {\cal L}^1(X,\bar{\cal M},\bar{\mu})$, is it true that $f \in {\cal L^1}(X,{\cal M},\mu)$ and $\int fd\mu = \int f d\bar{ \mu}$ ?

I guess it is not true because f isn’t nessesarily ${\cal M}$-measurable function.

But what if there is ${\cal M}$-measurable function g such that f=g almost everywhere?

Thank you.

Comment: You are right, if $\mathscr{X} \subset \mathscr{U}$ are two sigma algebras then $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathscr{X}, \mu) \subset \mathscr{L}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mu)$ but the two may differ, and will in general. For example, assume $\mu$ finite and take $\mathrm{E} \in \mathscr{U} \setminus \mathscr{X}$ and consider $\mathbf{1}_\mathrm{E}.$

In regards to your question about $g,$ either I don't get it or else, you are missing elementary facts about what $\in$ means.

Comment: Ah then the elementary function on E is measurable only on the larger sigma algebra! About $g$, I thought wrong. The dominated convergence thm is states as “($X, M, \mu$) is complete measure space. Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of complex-valued integrable functions. If $lim f_n = f \mu$-almost everywhere and $f_n$’s are all dominated by non-negative function $h$ in $L^1$ a.e., then the integral sign and limit sign can be interchanged” So I was wondering how I can deal with this theorem if the measure is not complete.